# Remove array items with RegExp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, arrays

I have a bunch of links that are used to filter information, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHxPL.png

When you click on a link, I add it to an array. For example:

```
Venue>All = venue-0, Venue>Home = venue-1, Venue>Away = venue-2, 
Vs>All = vs-0, Vs>Lefties = vs-1, Vs>Righties = vs-2
 etc, etc, etc.
```

If the user clicks "All" in any category, I want to search through the array and remove any items that contain that category. For example: `myArray['venue-1','venue-2','vs-1']`...click `Venue>all`, remove `'venue-1'` and `'venue-2'` leaving `myArray['vs-1']`.

Can I do this using a regular expression like: `/^venue/` and changing the word depending on which "All" you click?

I know I need to do a combination of `$.inArray` or `indexOf()` and `splice()` but I can't get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this simply with the `$.grep` utility:

```
var someArray = [1, 2, 3];

var numbersGreaterThanOne = $.grep(someArray, function(item)
{
    return item > 1;
});
```

This is just a sample, but you can perform whatever callback to filter elements that you like.

Comment: So how would I do this for what I need? I tried var filterIt = $.grep(filters,function(n,i){return n=/^venue/;}); but got nothing.

Comment: `return item.indexOf('venue') == -1` ? The test is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var newList = $.filter(function () {
    return this.indexOf('venue') != 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For a non-jQuery solution that mutates the array in-place:

```
for (var i=myArray.length;i--;){
  if (...) myArray.splice(i,1);
}
```

Where `...` is whatever test you want, such as:

```
if (myRegeEx.test(myArray[i]))
```